# Excel number format strings (e.g. "@", "$-409]d-mmm-yy;@") - Complete reference availability?

Tags: excel, number-formatting, spreadsheetgear

I'm using Spreadsheet Gear to do some Excel programming. I want more control over number formats and it appears that I need to use the `NumberFormat` property to achieve this.

I've seen suggestions that you can use "`@`" to specify a string for example, but can't find a complete reference on this.

I'm guessing it's Excel specific as opposed to Spreadsheet Gear specific.

Can anyone help me to find a full reference, or at least a decent list?

Comment: Anybody knows if there is any option for the string section "@" of this format, for example, "@@@@-@@@@" for adding dashes, just like "0000-0000" as in Zip Codes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a list of the [Number Format Codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for Excel.

Comment: Copy, paste, save! Thanks very much, I searched high and low for that.

Comment: link is down, just an FYI

Comment: They moved it. Fixed the link

Comment: Second option for link: Ecma-376 4th Edition Part 1, Section 18.8.31